# python-TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'(Learn Python the hard way)

Tags: python, automated-tests, python-requests, anaconda, nose

I am a newbie to Python, and am reading Zed Shaw's Learn Python the Hard Way but I met a problem in ex51, which is about automated testing in gettin input in Browser.

The automated testing code is just the same as in this website:
https://github.com/CreaturePhil/Learn-Python-the-Hard-Way/tree/master/ex51

However, the problem is:

```
ERROR: tests.app_tests.test_index
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 197, in
runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\projects\gothonweb\tests\app_tests.py", line 13, in test
_index
    assert_response(resp,contains="Nobody")
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\projects\gothonweb\tests\tools.py", line 8, in assert_re
sponse
    assert contains in resp.data,"Response does not contain %r"%contains
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.965s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

So I got a Type Error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.
I really tried some ways but still can not fix it, could someone help me?
Here are some of my codes:

`tests\app_tests.py`:

```
from nose.tools import *
from bin.app import app
from tests.tools import assert_response
def test_index():
    #check that we get a 404 on the /URL
    resp=app.request("/")
    assert_response(resp,status="404")
    #test our first GET request to /hello
    resp=app.request("/hello")
    assert_response(resp)
    #make sure default values work for the form
    resp=app.request("/hello",method="POST")
    assert_response(resp,contains="Nobody")
    #test that we get expected values
    data={'name':'Zed','greet':'Hola'}
    resp=app.request("/hello",method="POST",data=data)
    assert_response(resp,contains="Zed")
```

`tests\tools.py`:

```
from nose.tools import *
import re

def assert_response(resp,contains=None,matches=None,headers=None,status="200"):
    assert status in resp.status,"Expected response %r not in %r"% (status,resp.status)
    if status == "200":
        assert resp.data,"Response data is empty."
    if contains:
        assert contains in resp.data,"Response does not contain %r"%contains
    if matches:
        reg=re.compile(matches)
        assert reg.matches(resp.data),"Response does not match %r" %matches
    if headers:
        assert_equal(resp.headers,headers)
```

`bin\app.py`:

```
import web
urls=(
   '/hello','index'
)
app=web.application(urls,globals())
render=web.template.render('templates/',base="layout")
class index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()
    def POST(self):
        form=web.input(name="Nobody",greet="Hello")
        greeting="%s,%s"%(form.greet,form.name)
        return render.index(greeting=greeting)
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

I know that the author has advised to install Python 2.7. However,I installed 
the new edition of Anaconda, and use Python 3.6. I tried to create an environment
of Python 2.7 version but the same error still occurred.

I don't know why it happens and how to fix it, could someone help me?

Comment: FYI, the python community does not like 'learn python the hard way' very much, it's just not a particularly good book. Just very well known for some reason. You'd probably be much better served learning python with a tutorial that is based on python 3, since you absolutely should use python 3 over 2.

Comment: "I tried to create an environment of Python 2.7 version but the same error still occurred" => your env is broken then, this exact error can only happen with Python 3.

Comment: You ignored the author's advice, and used Python 3 instead of Python 2.

Comment: I **strongly** advice you to not use Learn Python The Hard Way, apart from the free edition being long outdated, the [the book has multiple issues in the way it teaches Python](https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If you want to learn programming using Python, and are using Python 3, I can recommend you use [*Think Python*](http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/) instead, which is much better organised.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Maybe I will think of other good books as soon as I finish this one(as there is only one excercise to finish). Maybe there's something wrong with my environment, but I actually created the environment according to codes in official website. Maybe the solution is to complete uninstall Anaconda and install Python 2.7 and try it again,although it is too time-consuming.